# Infer type of protobuf Any value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers

I have a value which is of type `Google::Protobuf::Any`. I want to unpack it by doing something like below:

```
 any_value = Google::Protobuf::Any.new(
          type_url: 'type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Int64Value',
          value:    '1'
        )
 type = Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup(any_value.type_name)
 value = any_value.unpack(type)
```

Unfortunately, the `type` always comes back as nil, leading to an error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `descriptor' for nil:NilClass
```

`any_value.type_name` is not nil. When I print it out, it is:

```
google.protobuf.Int64Value
```

What am I doing wrong?